# SSL Error on apache server

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslerrorhandler

I have updated SSL certificate and private key in `httpd.conf` file when we are checking the URL I am getting error like cross symbol. When I click that symbol and click the details:

It's showing error like:

> Issued: localhost localdomain

Here is the vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>

   SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/public.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/private.key

    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What domain has been issued the certificate? What URL are you using to get this error?

Comment: How did you generate the key? what are the details used for key generation?